# Postgresql - Unable to CREATE/INSERT via Pygresql

Tags: python, postgresql

```
In [50]: cur.execute('create table xyzabcd (c1 integer, c2 text)')
Out[50]: <pgdb.pgdbCursor at 0x344ed501d0>
```

But in psql if I try `\dt`, I cannot see the table. If I copy paste the exact same query into psql, the table is created. Then if I try to execute the above in Python, I get a `ProgrammingError: ERROR:  relation "xyzabcd" already exists`.

Same story goes with inserts. SELECTs work flawlessly though. I've tried the same on another Postgresql server as well (both on RDS)

Any clue what might be going on? I'm connecting to via the same credentials in both psql and Python-pygresql.

Before anyone asks, I cannot use Psycopg2 because of license issues.

Postgresql Server 9.3.3, psql 9.3.5, Pygresql 4.1.1

Comment: Have you committed the transaction?

Comment: 9.3.3 has a very serious replication bug, upgrade immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `commit()` method of your dbconnection. In PostgreSQL all DDL (CREATE TABLE) are in transaction. In Python DB API 2 autocommit is off by default.